# Why doesn't this Apache <If> expression work?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I can't seem to be able to use this expression in an  directive properly. Can anyone help me with the syntax, or am I doing something else wrong? (hostname: example.local, Apache v2.4)

```
# Only apply enclosed directives if hostname does not end with ".local"
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} !~ /\.+local$/">
  # Use test php.ini recursivly
  suPHP_ConfigPath /example.com
</If>
```

Comment: What is improper about it? What is the result when you try to use this code, and why is that wrong?

Comment: The conditional is not working. The suPHP_ConfigPath directive is being applied when the hostname contains ".local". Wrong in my case because the server is on Windows so the suConfig doesn't exist, while it does on Linux. I've proven this by replacing the suConfig directive with the Error directive which also gets applied.

Comment: Looks like a https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem.

Comment: None of these expressions will prevent the directives within the <If> from being applied either: `code"2=3 , 2==3,  2 eq 3,  2 =~ /3/"`

Comment: Now I'm narrowing it down LOL: `code"false"` doesn't work either. This is the very first example of a Backus-Naur expression in the documentation at [link](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html)

Answer (score 0):

This directive solves my particular problem:

```
<IfDirective suPHP_ConfigPath>
  suPHP_ConfigPath (path to php.ini)
</IfDirective>
```

But doesn't answer the question about the If directive.